# Drop all characters in string after specific character?

Tags: r

The title speaks for it self. I've got this string

```
"Dog - food"
```

I want to drop all characters following the specific character "-"

Including the specific character chosen. This is my desired output

```
"Dog"
```

This is only a simple example. I intend to use this on much larger and dynamic strings.

Comment: `trimws(sub("-.*", "", mystring))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that gsub function works fine for that action

```
gsub( " .*$", "", "Dog - food" )
## "Dog"
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you define the character that should tell every character after to drop? Isn't this just dropping everything past the first word, or everything past a space?

Comment: A space (), then any character (.) any number of times (*) until the end of the string ($). See ?regex to learn regular expressions. It drops everything not after the space, including itself.

Comment: I take it then, that space could be any character. Okay cool, thank you

Answer (score 1):

An option is `word`

```
library(stringr)
word(str1, 1)
#[1] "Dog"
```

---

Or with `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(str1, whitespace = "\\s*-.*")
#[1] "Dog"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Dog - food"
```

Comment: That stringr one is definitely handy